# jQuery: spin plus to minus font awesome icon, on accordion section click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I am trying to learn how to rotate/ spin a plus sign icon into a minus sign on click.

I saw the effect on the vAccordion by [Lukasz Watroba](http://lukaszwatroba.github.io/v-accordion/).

Right now I am only capable to have the code toggle the plus icon to a minus icon, but without the spin/ convert effect:

**Mark-up:**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
           Collapsible Group Item #2 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function toggleSign(e) {
  $(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-heading')
    .find('i')
    .toggleClass('fa fa-minus fa fa-plus');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleSign);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleSign);
```

Hope to get some positive help here as always, to find out how to achieve the effect I need.

Many thanks.

Comment: vAccordion does it with CSS transforms and transitions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want the plus/minus to seamlessly transition, you could use pseudo elements rather than font icons (that's how it's being done in the example you provided). In doing so, you can avoid using any additional jQuery as well.

In the example below, the icon changes based on the `.collapsed` class that is automatically toggled on the `.accordion-toggle` element. The opacity of the `::after` pseudo element is toggled to create the transition you're trying to achieve.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1crd75rs/)

Snippet below:

```css
.accordion-toggle {
  position: relative;
}
.accordion-toggle::before,
.accordion-toggle::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -22px;
  width: 14px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-top: -2px;
  background-color: #000;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
.accordion-toggle::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed::after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
           Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, if you still want to use font awesome, you could use the following. Unfortunately, the transition isn't going to be as smooth as the one above because you can't transition between two icons like you can transition between pseudo elements.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/L8yuerp3/)

Snippet below:

```js
function toggleChevron(e) {
  $(e.target)
    .prev('.panel-heading')
    .find("i")
    .toggleClass('fa fa-minus fa fa-plus');
}
$('#accordion').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
```

```css
.accordion-toggle + .fa {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s;
  transition: all 0.25s;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed + .fa {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1 
        </a><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
           Collapsible Group Item #2 
        </a><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3 
        </a><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> 
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Collapsible Content #3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Josh, and thank you for your answer. I have a question, is it possible you can show me this using font awesome icons?

Comment: @erasmocarlos Updated.

Comment: I like how it looks using pseudo elements. To be honest, I have been trying to figure out the styling for the (+-) signs so they have a similar look and feel as in the example I found online, but I am not sure to which class I need to apply the CSS properties. Thank you for the additional example.

Comment: @erasmocarlos I updated the first example. It looks similar now.

Comment: Thank you Josh. Would you tell me how can I apply color to the plus and minus signs?

Comment: @erasmocarlos Change the background color of the pseudo elements - http://jsfiddle.net/6m3ejgy6/

Comment: Got it Josh, I changed background-color: #000; to background-color: #00abef;

Comment: Thank you Josh, awesome answer!

Comment: do you know how to allow all the tabs to be all expanded when clicked? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add animation for this object http://jsfiddle.net/ntd9fkzu/8/

```
** above this fiddle may help you **
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your help. I added the animation part but I did not see it doing anything different. I put a fiddle with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/itortu/ntd9fkzu/

Comment: It works but not consistently. Only the first time you click on each section, and only when it expands, the animation/ transform does not perform when collapsing the section. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for modifying this fiddle. It looks like it's working better. The only thing I noticed is that the rotation does not repeat when collapsing. Regards.